# PHP Split a sting if it has a space and detect if its been split

Tags: php

I need to pass two variables with no spaces to a web service so that i dont get an invalid response.

`$firstname` and `$surname`

I need to make these variables from a variable called `$display_name`

Display name may or may not contain a space. It will usually be something like 'Joe Smith' or 'JoeSmith'

So i cant just do (because with 'JoeSmith' I will get no surname)

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $display_name);
$firstname = $pieces[0]; // Joe
$surname   = $pieces[1]; // Smith
```

likewise i cannot do (because of the potential space)

```
$firstname = $display_name; // Joe Smith
$surname   = $display_name; // Joe Smith
```

How can i ensure both firstname and surname are populated with no spaces. Even if the display name was 'Joe T Smith'?

Comment: Post expected values for first and surname for special cases such as JoeSmith, Joe T Smith, etc.

Comment: Do you want to have 'JoeSmith' separated into `$firstname='Joe'` and `$surname='Smith'`? Also what values should these have, if there's a display name like 'Joe T Smith'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (count($pieces) < 2)
{
    // Wasn't split
}
else
{
    //Was split into at least two pieces
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional statement to see if the split was successful, if it was do the first code block, if it wasn't do the second code block